# BN_print_fp() function always output a BIGNUM object by hex in OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl

I am using OpenSSL library. I write a piece of code as following:

```
    BIGNUM* a;
    BIGNUM* b;
    BIGNUM* p;
    
    a = BN_new();
    b = BN_new();
    p = BN_new();
    
    BN_dec2bn(&a, "1");
    BN_dec2bn(&b, "1");
    BN_dec2bn(&p, "23");

    printf("a=");
    BN_print_fp(stdout, a);
    printf("\n");
    printf("b=");
    BN_print_fp(stdout, b);
    printf("\n");
    printf("p=");
    BN_print_fp(stdout, p);
    printf("\n");
```

When run it , it always output as following:

```
a=1
b=1
p=17
```

As I excepted, p should be 23. But `hex(23) = 0x17`, where is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BN_print.html):

> `BN_print()` and `BN_print_fp()` write the hexadecimal encoding of `a`, with a leading '-' for negative numbers, to the `BIO` or `FILE fp`.

So nothing's wrong; it's working as expected. If you want to print out a bignum in base 10:

```c
char *as_str = BN_bn2dec(p);
printf("p=%s\n", as_str);
OPENSSL_free(as_str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to print a number in base 10.